# Recycler view not displaying any items from my database

Tags: sqlite, android-studio, android-recyclerview

Im trying to display my data in my database which has 3 columns (Task, date and status) using recyclerview but it does not work. I am not sure if its because I am not inputting the data correctly (I am using speech recognizer to input) or I am doing something wrong with the database. I am very new to programming in Android Studio and amateur at coding in general so thanks in advance

My code :

To load into the recyclerview screen from main activity:

```
    view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View view) {
              Intent view_action = new Intent(MainActivity.this, viewscreen.class);
              startActivity(view_action);
         }
      });
```

My database manager class:

```
package com.ia;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import java.util.Date;

public class DatabaseManager extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "task_database";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "task_table";
    public static final String COLUMN_DATE = "date";
    public static final String COLUMN_STRING = "task";

    public static final String COLUMN_STATUS = "status";

    public SQLiteDatabase dB;


    public DatabaseManager(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase dB) {
        String createTableQuery = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (" +
                COLUMN_DATE + " TEXT PRIMARY KEY, " +
                COLUMN_STRING + " TEXT," +
                COLUMN_STATUS + "INTEGER)";
        dB.execSQL(createTableQuery);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase dB, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Handle schema upgrades if needed
    }

    public void openDatabase(){
        dB = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public void insertTask(String task, String date){
        dB = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COLUMN_STRING, task);
        cv.put(COLUMN_STATUS, 0);
        cv.put(COLUMN_DATE, date);
    }

    public void deleteTask(String task){           //Work in progress (Deleting tasks)
        dB.delete(TABLE_NAME, task + "=?", new String[] {String.valueOf(task)});
    }

    public SQLiteDatabase getDataBase(){
        return dB;
    }

    public Cursor getData(){
        dB = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = dB.rawQuery("Select * from task_table", null);
        return cursor;
    }
}
```

My data adapter class:

```
package com.ia;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.List;


public class DataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DataAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private Context context;
    private List<String> Task_ID;
    private List<String> Date_ID;
    private List<String> Status_ID;

    public DataAdapter(Context context, List<String> Task_ID, List<String> Date_ID, List<String> Status_ID) {
        this.context = context;
        this.Task_ID = Task_ID;
        this.Date_ID = Date_ID;
        this.Status_ID = Status_ID;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.Task_ID.setText(Task_ID.get(position));
        holder.Date_ID.setText(Date_ID.get(position));
        holder.Status_ID.setText(Status_ID.get(position));
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount(){
        return 0;
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView Task_ID;
        public TextView Date_ID;
        public TextView Status_ID;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            Task_ID = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textTask);
            Date_ID = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textDate);
            Status_ID = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textStatus);
        }
    }
}
```

My recyclerview class:

```
package com.ia;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class viewscreen extends AppCompatActivity {
    public RecyclerView recyclerView;
    public ArrayList<String> task;
    public ArrayList<String> date;
    public ArrayList<String> status;
    public DatabaseManager dM;
    public DataAdapter adapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_viewscreen);
        dM = new DatabaseManager(this);
        task = new ArrayList<>();
        date = new ArrayList<>();
        status = new ArrayList<>();
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.RecyclerView);
        adapter = new DataAdapter(this, task, date, status);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        displaydata();
    }

    private void displaydata() {
        Cursor cursor = dM.getData();
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            task.add(cursor.getString(0));
            date.add(cursor.getString(1));
            status.add(cursor.getString(2));
        }
    }
}
```

My recycler view layout xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".viewscreen">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/RecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

My layout for each item in recyclerview :

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:cardElevation="12dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="16dp"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:backgroundTint="#efefef">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">

            <TextView
                style="bold"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Task"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="24dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textTask"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize = "24dp"
                android:textColor = "@color/black"
                style = "bold"/>

        </LinearLayout>



        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">

            <TextView
                style="bold"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Date"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="24dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textDate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize = "24dp"
                android:textColor = "@color/black"
                style = "bold"/>

        </LinearLayout>



        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">

            <TextView
                style="bold"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="status"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="24dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textStatus"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize = "24dp"
                android:textColor = "@color/black"
                style = "bold"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Finally, the code which I use to insert data into the database.

```
@Override
    public void onResults(Bundle results) {
        ArrayList<String> speechResults = results.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
        String task = "";
        String date = "";
        if (speechResults != null && !speechResults.isEmpty()) {
            String input = speechResults.get(0); //Whole input is one string
            input = input.replaceAll(" ", "/");
            String[] wordsArray = input.split("/");
            ArrayList<String> processedSpeechResults = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(wordsArray)); //String is split into multiple elements in another array
            Toast.makeText(this, processedSpeechResults.get(0), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            for (int i = 0; i<2; i++){
                date = date + processedSpeechResults.get(i);
            }
            for (int i = 3; i < processedSpeechResults.size(); i++) {
                Toast.makeText(this, processedSpeechResults.get(i), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                task = task + processedSpeechResults.get(i);
            }
            dM.insertTask(task, date); //dM is a previously defined DatabaseManager object
        }
```

Thanks guys